# Vue.js Redirect to Named Route?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, redirect, vue-component, vue-router

I am working on a vue.js project. 
I have a route  with following configuration

```
{
  path: '/Cart',
  component: Cart,
  props: (route) => ({
   payment_id: route.query.payment_id,
   payment_request_id: route.query.payment_request_id
  })
}
```

My Scenario is cart - > Payment(third party) --(redirection to)--->cart.

During redirection the url gets appened as www.example.com/cart?payment_id='xxx'

the route is not able to identify that cart page is requested?

Any help would be gladly appreciated?

Note: I use `window.location.href` to navigate to payment page.

Comment: Please provide the code. did you tried to use this.$router.push ?

Comment: Are you sure there is no errors in the console?

Comment: All Spa's have this Problem, the solution is redirect to index page when a particular Page is requested. https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html

Comment: Yea, Thanks for the link. I wonder how can i redirect, if i am serving HTML pages from a static Bucket.

Answer (score 0):

```
    routes: [
    { path: '/a', redirect: { name: 'foo' }}
  ]
```

The Docs

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/redirect-and-alias.html#redirect